# dynamically add and delete input fields in react

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a React form where user can upload an image. I am using a function createObjectURL() as given below which i set as the state.

This is the image component

```
<Row className="form-row">
                    <Col md={8} className="image-field">
                        <div className="input-image-file">
                            <img src={this.state.image} className="myimage" alt="choose an image"></img>
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={4} className="image-buttons">
                        <Row className="form-row"> 
                            <FormControl type="file" onChange={this.onImageChange.bind(this)} ></FormControl>
                        </Row>
                        <Row className="form-row">
                            <Button className="delete-image" onClick={this.deleteImage.bind(this)}><i className="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</Button>
                        </Row>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
```

this is the onImageChange and deleteImage function

```
onImageChange(event){
    this.setState({image: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])},()=>{
        console.log(this.state.image)
    })
}

deleteImage(){
    this.setState({image : null})
}
```

the URL is like

```
"blob:http://localhost:3000/e5531071-c8fc-46db-a934-98678c1cec3a"
```

I send this data to backend and create an entry in mongodb also where is the URL is saved correctly. I have an option called edit which retrieves all the contents of the form for the user to edit. All contents are getting displayed except the Image.
**I get an error like**

GET blob:http://localhost:3000/e5531071-c8fc-46db-a934-98678c1cec3a 404 (Not Found)

please do help me thanks in advance [this is the console error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fuXU.png)

Comment: Are you storing path of uploaded image in database or storing image itself in database using base64?

Comment: i am just storing the url of the image @Ratnadeep